# How to "invert" frequency and preserve its probability distribution?

Tags: python, probability, distribution

lets say I have the a list of frequency.

```
class 1 => 9
class 2 => 5
class 3 => 6
class 4 => 100
```

Convert them into probability where sum = # of total occurrence
0.075, 0.0417, 0.05, 0.83

Assuming there are 500 classes, my goal is to select n number, says 20, out of these 500 classes randomly with its probability unproportion to its frequency.

So, I want class 1 ( frequency = 9) to have more probability of being picked than class 2 (frequency of 5)  and class 3 (frequency of 6) but less than class 4 (frequency of 100). Same logic applies to the rest of the classes.

Also, I want that the probability of these classes being picked is proportional to one another. Class 4 (83%) is about 11 time more likely of begin picked compared to class 1 (7.5%). Again, same logic applies to the rest of the classes.

Back to what I actually am dealing with, I have about 3000 classes, and about 95 percent of them have probability of frequency of about 0.1%. and the few 5 percent have say 40% 20% 3%. (range is quite large among these 5 percent and even the smallest of this group is still significantly larger than other 95 percent). In addition to this, I need to select among of

For this reason I can't really use Monte Carlo method where I select threshold and select the class when generated random number is higher than the class probability.

My friend suggests that we subtract these number from 1. so low probability now have higher change of being picked. but because the probability of the 95 percent is very low. Doing as my friend suggests whould almost garantee than the each member of the 95 percent group will be picked almost with certainty.

Answer (score 0):

It's crude, but you could do this:

```
a = random.random()

if (a < 0.075) 
    print('1')

if (a >= 0.075 && a < 0.075 + 0.0417):
    print('2')

#etc...
```

Convert the probabilities to a list of variables and run a loop through them. Then do this 20 times. Would this work?